# jQuery. Remove "required" on hidden element when submit

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, required

I manage to do checkbox list that makes dropdown options to show and hide when clicking on check boxes, and when I don't check any of the check boxes the basic dropdown options will show only and those dropdown options are required to choose before clicking on submit.

The problem is when any of check boxes are selected the basic dropdown options become hidden and the other dropdown options shows, but when click on submit button the message pupup outside the browser shows that there is still fields are required, which the hidden dropdown options.

I want to make those dropdown options to be not required when it hide.

**here is the code for checkbox:**

```
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
            var thisClass = $j(this).attr('class');
            if ($j(this).attr('checked')) {
                $j(':checkbox.' + thisClass + ":not(#" + this.id + ")").removeAttr('checked');
            }
            else {
                $j(this).attr('checked', false);
                $j('.main-options').show();
                $j('.first-image').show();
                $j('.hide-onload').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

**and this is the code for show/hide:**

```
    $j(document).ready(function(e) {
        $j('.roundedOne').each(function(index, element) {
            $j(this).click(function(){
                $j('.main-options').hide();
                $j('.first-image').hide();
                $j('.hide-onload').hide();

                $j('.changing-options').eq(index).show();
                $j('.changing-image').eq(index).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

I hope I was clear.

Comment: Are you using jqueryvalidation ?

Comment: If you are using jqueryvalidation you can use ignore property, please check this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validate-plugin-do-not-validate-hidden-elements

Comment: Actually, I am using Magento validation but I added new fields to the main contact form with jquery stuff so it been mixed now, I use "required" attribute only when i need something to be required. here is the link of the page: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/contacts/ still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution using jquery.

> ...find('input, textarea, select') **you can add more elements that you need to go through inside your form**

```
$('form#csf3SubmitForm').find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop('required') && $(this).is(":hidden") && $(this).val() === ""){
         console.log("before -- IS REQUIRED >>> " +  $(this).prop('required') + " -- ID >>> " + $(this).attr("id") + " " + "VALUE >>> "  + $(this).val());
         $(this).prop("required", false);
         console.log("after -- IS REQUIRED >>> " +  $(this).prop('required') + " -- ID >>> " + $(this).attr("id") + " " + "VALUE >>> "  + $(this).val());
     }
 });
```

If you have many fields on your form and forgot to add further validation to NOT require invisible fields, you can loop through all the fields inside your and check which are required and are NOT visible...

Set those elements to required=false. You can add more to the condition to be specific on which field or fields you are targeting to disable.

Hope this helps and gives an idea. This is a workaround.